# O que é FarmHash?

Tags: hash

Recentemente, descobri o [`FarmHash`](https://github.com/google/farmhash). Aparentemente, é uma implementação para se fazer hash de algum dado. Fiquei com algumas dúvidas:

- Ele se comporta da mesma forma como os hashes mais comuns, como `md5` ou `sha`?
- Qual é a sua principal diferença em relação aos referidos hashes mais "comuns"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ele se comporta da mesma forma como os hashes mais comuns, como md5 ou sha?

Não, a resposta está no próprio link como "The functions mix the input bits thoroughly but are not suitable for cryptography.". A diferença entre o `SHA-256` e o `FarmHash` (assim como o `SipHash`, `MetroHash`, `CityHash`, `HighwayHash` e o famoso `CRC32`) é que o `SHA-256` é uma hash criptograficamente segura e todas as outras não.

Essas hashes não-criptograficas são usads para hash-tables, alguns algorítimos (como o SipHash) foram desenvolvidos para mitigar o ataque de [Hash-DoS](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/glossary/hash-dos-attack) ou [Hash-Flooding DoS](https://asfws12.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/asfws2012-jean_philippe_aumasson-martin_bosslet-hash_flooding_dos_reloaded.pdf). Já outros, como o `CRC32` foi feito para verificar erros e corrupções acidentais.

- Qual é a sua principal diferença em relação aos referidos hashes mais "comuns"?

As criptograficamente-segura tem critérios de segurança muito maiores, por exemplo devem ser imprevisíveis (*"random oracle"*) e ser resistente à colisões. Qualquer hash terá colisões, devido ao [*principio da casa de pombos*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_casa_dos_pombos), uma vez que a saída da hash tem 256 bits e a entrada tem infinitas. Entretanto, as hashes seguras são feitas para que seja dificil de encontrar uma colisão. Isso também garante que seja resistente a segunda pré-imagem.

Apesar dessas hashes não serem uma hash segura, elas podem ser outra coisa... Algumas dessas hashes (como o SipHash, talvez outras) podem ser considerada um PRF ou MAC criptograficamente seguro. Isso é, você pode trocar o  `GCM`, `HMAC` e o `Poly1305` pelo `SipHash`. Mas, lembre-se que as condições de um MAC são mais baixas do que de uma hash, um MAC não é suposto a ser seguro contra colisões (embora também possa ser como o `HMAC`).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, são hashes para fins não-criptográficos. Tipo, podem ser bons para um hashmap, para um índice de banco de dados, mas não para criptografia.

Os hashes "comuns", no sentido de populares, são os criptográficos, como MD5 e SHA-1. Tais hashes oferecem duas garantias:

a) garantia fraca: Dada uma informação A e seu hash H(A), é muito difícil forjar B tal que H(B) = H(A).

b) garantia forte: É muito difícil achar quaisquer valores A e B tal que H(A) = H(B).

Geralmente quando se diz que um hash foi quebrado, o que foi quebrado foi a "garantia forte", a garantia fraca continua valendo por mais um tempo. Acho que as duas já foram pro saco no caso do MD5, e a garantia forte no caso do SHA-1.